# Azure DevOps: I want to change a date field of all the child work items when I change the date of a parent

Tags: azure-devops

I want to update **Target Date** of a parent and expecting this would change **Go-Live Date** (Target date + 3) of all the child work items associated with it.
Is it possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.